# How can I pin Cygwin.bat to my Windows 10 start screen?

Tags: windows-10, cygwin, start-screen

Seems you can't pin a .bat directly for some reason.

Is there a way to have Cygwin's bash launched from my start screen?

Update : BTW, I followed the advice in some of the "duplicate questions" eg. make a shortcut and do that, and it seems you can't pin shortcuts to bat files in Windows 10 either.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit of a PITA, but you can do it.

- Make a shortcut to the batch file you want (save it on your desktop or someplace).
- Open up the Run dialog (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>).
- Run `shell:programs`.
- Copy the shortcut you made into the folder it opens.
- Reboot, and log back in.
- Your batch file should now show up under Start -> All Apps.
- Right-click it and select Pin to Start.

Comment: I didn't find it necessary to reboot, but otherwise, this works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

You probably don't want to launch bash, you want to launch a terminal which runs bash within it. The cygwin installation should have placed a shortcut to 'Cygwin Terminal' on your desktop. Pin that to the taskbar/Start menu and off you go.

If you don't see a shortcut for it (it actually launches the mintty terminal program) just run the cygwin setup through to completion (it will do an update on your existing packages if you don't select anything extra) and on the final dialog check the boxes for "Create icon on Desktop" and "Add icon to Start Menu" and you will have it. You can link that one to the taskbar to be able to launch your terminal whenever you want.

Comment: Indeed, the MinTTY terminal is superior to the Windows command window. It's been available as the default Cygwin terminal for quite some time now.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't re-run Setup.exe : To (re-)create the regular CYGWIN terminal (that starts bash and your login environement) and pin it to your taskbar in windows 10 (or any other windows!):

- open the file browser ( <kbd>windows</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>)
- go to your CYGWIN directory (note that this can be (moved) anywhere you wish, but it should be by default probably underneath `C:\program files` (or `c:\program files (x86)`, depending on your versions)
- go to the `.....\wherever\CYGWIN\bin` subfolder

  - find and right-click on `mintty.exe`, and choose `send to` -> `Desktop (create shortcut)`
- Go to your Desktop, right-click on the `mintty.exe - shortcut` and choose `properties`

  - Edit the Target: by adding, at the end : a space followed by the option: `"-"`, so that `.....\wherever\CYGWIN\bin\mintty.exe` becomes `.....\wherever\CYGWIN\bin\mintty.exe "-"`
  - Make sure the field `started in:`, underneath, has the same path `.....\wherever\CYGWIN\bin`
  - and if you want the right icon, click on `change icon...` (near the bottom), and go to `.....\wherever\CYGWIN\` and choose the `Cygwin-Terminal.ico`.
- double-click that shortcut (once correctly edited), and if the window opens correctly and everything seems ok : right-click on the icon that appeared on your taskbar, and choose to `pin it to taskbar`

Please note: that I don't have the english version of windows, so the details above may vary (I tried to reconstruct the correct field names from memory...)